# CREATE TABLE using LIKE and adding the same PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to create a table based on the schema of another table. The LIKE option does this and copies dist/sort keys as well as columns and data types for columns. But it doesn't copy primary keys.

How can I create a table using LIKE *and* set the primary key in the new table to be the same as in the old?

This throws an error: `Error: syntax error at or near "PRIMARY"`

```
CREATE TABLE new_123 (
    LIKE old_123 INCLUDING DEFAULTS
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

`id` is a column in the old table.

Comment: I can break it into 2 statements: create and alter to add the PK. But wondering if there's a way to do it in 1.

Comment: The documentation says _"Tables created with the LIKE option don't inherit primary and foreign key constraints. Distribution style, sort keys, BACKUP, and NULL properties are inherited by LIKE tables, but you can't explicitly set them in the CREATE TABLE ... LIKE statement."_, so it would appear you cannot achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit vague, but if I've understood correctly, you basically want a glorified "Copy and Paste Table Schema" type command so you don't have to re-type the whole ugly create table command.

This is how to do it in MySQL;

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table_name;
```

Then simply copy the output from that command, paste into MySQL Workbench and press go (with your new table name...)